# How to use the Python terminal function in Java

Tags: java, python, macos, terminal

I have an interesting problem. I need to be able to have a window that allows users input commands as if they were in a terminal and using python. When you type in 'python' on a mac it allows you to run a python commands. I can access the 'python' function, but it will not let me write python commands to the terminal through my custom command line interface.

Does

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String text = textField.getText();
            try {

                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(text);

            //Nothing after this line
            } catch (IOException i) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                i.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

As you can see I have an event listener that runs every time a button is clicked. 
When I type 'python' in my command line it will not allow me to type in the sub command line, for python commands. I have a feeling it is because of this line:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(text);
```

Any suggestions to allow me to use my python commands?

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 0):

Your Process is at risk of blocking the Swing event thread. To prevent this from happening, and to prevent you from running out of OS buffer for the Process's OutputStream, I suggest,

1. Run your Process in a background thread.
2. Attach stream listeners to your Process including using an InputStreamReader for the Process's InputStream, an InputStreamReader for the Process's ErrorStream, and push text into the Process's OutputStream. Putting it into a PrintStream would work well for this.
3. Do this InputStream processing in their own threads as well.
4. Unrelated recommendation that you consider using a ProcessBuilder as perhaps a cleaner way of getting your Process.